# http hook/callback with ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

From ejabberd's webpage, I learn that one can extend ejabberd's functionality by writing modules using hooks/events etc. However, all the examples are in erlang, which I don't really know how to use. Of course, I can go learn it, but my question is whether I can avoid it altogether. Namely, is the following possible:

I write some REST server (using something else, like node.js/golang/python whatever), and then somehow hook it into ejabberd's event system.

What is the best way to go about this? Any link to a code example/tutorial would be great!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is sort of like asking if you can hack core Linux kernel modules without being forced to use C. Besides, every language you mentioned sucks *way worse* to write both event handlers *and* network code than the one ejabberd is already written in -- which goes a long way to explaining why it was written in Erlang to begin with. If Erlang were hard I would maybe see a point, but having written network services in several languages I feel confident saying that learning Erlang is *much* easier than writing a solid network service that does something non-trivial in most other languages.

Comment: I understand that erlang is great, but there are other reasons why one might choose other languages, one of which is availability of off the shelf components which save a lot of development time. Suppose I want to write some kind of a bot. Would something like this work? Write a minimal hook in erlang which essentially calls a remote REST server. The server then talks to the ejabberd cluster using some client api.

Comment: If you want to run a chat service that does not yet exist, and attach a bot to it that also does not yet exist, and you don't want to use Erlang if possible, then I would recommend using a chat server that's not ejabberd (or Erlang based). If you *need* to use ejabberd or MongooseIM or some XMPP service for some reason, and want to attach a bot I would recommend you use an XMPP client lib in OtherLang, connect via XMPP and react to events (which means you can probably cobble an existing IRC bot by rewriting the IRC-only bits).

Comment: If you want to do something more advanced, like run a MUD over XMPP and fundamentally change the way service events work -- then the work involved will vastly outweigh the learning curve of whatever libs and protocols you wind up using, and the learning curve of whatever those libs and protocols are will vastly outweigh the learning curve of whatever language they are implemented in.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of feature you want to write. For some modules, you may want to use the internal API. Please note that you can use Erlang or Elixir, which is much easier. For example, here is how to write an Elixir module:
https://blog.process-one.net/elixir-sips-ejabberd-with-elixir-part-1/

The other approach is to use the Jabber XMPP component protocol. It is more limited but allow you to write XMPP components in any languages. Here is a description of Jabber component protocol, supported by ejabberd:
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html